# Find the value of $k$ for $f(x|y)$

Tags: probability

Let $Y$ a  uniform random variable in $[0,1]$, and let $X$ a uniform variable in $[1,e^Y]$

Find $f(x|y)$ and $f_y(y)$

We know $X\sim \mathcal{U}[1,e^Y]$ and $Y\sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$ then by definition of uniform distribution, we have:

$f(x|y)= \begin{cases}  k & 1 \le x \le e^y \\0 & otherwise,\\\end{cases}$

and $f_y(y)=\begin{cases}  t & 0 \le y \le 1 \\0 & otherwise,\\\end{cases}$

Then, i need find the value of $t$ and $k$.

For $f_y(y)$ by definition of density function, $t=1$. But for $f(x|y)$ i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The integral of a pdf from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ (the total area under the curve) must be 1.  Therefore, $k$ is $(e^{y}-1)^{-1}$.  Similarly for $t$.

Comment: @Graham Kemp  oops.  Thanks.  :)